# downloading multiple urls using a downloadtask

Tags: java, json, android-studio, object

hi im trying to write a code in which im trying to download multiple urls using a downloadtask and convert them into json objects and then adding them to a list,but i only get one object multiple times instead of different each time,my code is:

```
    int x = 1;  
    while(x<=6) {

        try {
            
            result = tasknew.execute("url"parts[x]+ "rest of the url").get();
           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        

        try {
           
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            Log.i("title", title);
            listobject.add(title);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        x=x+1;
    }



    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

hey guys i figured out the answer , since an async task can only be run once,that is why my downloadtask only excecuted once.so in order to run it multiple time just replace the news = new Downloadtask..that will work